# Where to find attribute description

Tags: arcgis-desktop, streets, documentation

I've received a Arcgis layer containing streets, represented by polylines. When I identify a specific street, a large attribute table pops up:

```
OBJECTID
Shape
LINK_ID
ST_NAME
FEAT_ID
ST_LANGCD
NUM_STNMES
ST_NM_PREF
ST_TYP_BEF
ST_NM_BASE
ST_NM_SUFF
ST_TYP_AFT
ST_TYP_ATT
ADDR_TYPE
L_REFADDR
L_NREFADDR
L_ADDRSCH
L_ADDRFORM
R_REFADDR
R_NREFADDR
R_ADDRSCH
R_ADDRFORM
REF_IN_ID
NREF_IN_ID
N_SHAPEPNT
FUNC_CLASS
SPEED_CAT
FR_SPD_LIM
TO_SPD_LIM
TO_LANES
FROM_LANES
ENH_GEOM
LANE_CAT
DIVIDER
DIR_TRAVEL
L_AREA_ID
R_AREA_ID
L_POSTCODE
R_POSTCODE
L_NUMZONES
R_NUMZONES
NUM_AD_RNG
AR_AUTO
AR_BUS
AR_TAXIS
AR_CARPOOL
AR_PEDEST
AR_TRUCKS
AR_TRAFF
AR_DELIV
AR_EMERVEH
PAVED
PRIVATE
FRONTAGE
BRIDGE
TUNNEL
RAMP
TOLLWAY
POIACCESS
CONTRACC
ROUNDABOUT
INTERINTER
UNDEFTRAFF
FERRY_TYPE
MULTIDIGIT
MAXATTR
SPECTRFIG
INDESCRIB
MANOEUVRE
DIVIDERLEG
INPROCDATA
FULL_GEOM
URBAN
ROUTE_TYPE
DIRONSIGN
EXPLICATBL
NAMEONRDSN
POSTALNAME
STALENAME
VANITYNAME
JUNCTIONNM
EXITNAME
SCENIC_RT
SCENIC_NM
TO_X_LANES
FR_X_LANES
FOURWHLDR
COVERIND
PLOT_ROAD
REVERSIBLE
EXPR_LANE
CARPOOLRD
PHYS_LANES
VER_TRANS
PUB_ACCESS
LOW_MBLTY
PARK_AVAIL
PRIORITYRD
SPD_LM_SRC
TRANS_AREA
L_FIPS
R_FIPS
L_STATE
R_STATE
L_CITY
R_CITY
MEANDER
DRIVE_TIME
L_ROUTE
R_ROUTE
FROM_ELEV
TO_ELEV
OLD_LROUTE
OLD_RROUTE
BREADTH
WALK_TIME
WALK_PEN
NO_PARK_L
NO_PARK_R
TRAVCONS
LEFT_NOTE
RIGHT_NOTE
FT_PENALTY
TF_PENALTY
FUTURNRES
TUTURNRES
AR_MOTOR
EXPAND_INC
DCA
DISTANCE
Serv_Time
RSOwner
RSClass
RSDivision
RSRoadClass
RSPaveClass
Route_Num
Beltway
Service Left
Service Right
# of Passes Left
# of Passes Right
Left Priority
Right Priority
Left Range
Right Range
RS_Truck
RS_ServiceLeft
RS_ServiceRight
RS_TUTURNRES
RS_FUTURNRES
RS_MISC
RS_5T_TRAVCONS
RS_1T_TRAVCONS
RS_HOOD_L
RS_HOOD_R
Shape_Length
```

Although I suspect that there are some custom attributes in this table, the majority of the attributes in the table are listed here: `http://webapub.sjrwmd.com/arcgis/rest/services/srvc/srRegMapExcnty/MapServer/17`

Is there a way to find a description of these attributes? Searching for 'arcgis street attributes/fields/...' does not yield any solutions. Since I'm new to arcgis, I've no idea where to start searching. Searching for some specific attribute names did not yield any results. This external page http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/Import/ArcView gave some insights, but only a few attributes are defined there.

Similarly, is there somewhere more information on a polyline? I need to create a graph, exactly like this: [Generating graph edge list from polyline and point shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158409/generating-graph-edge-list-from-polyline-and-point-shapefiles)
Although I understand the proposed solution, it seems really error-prone to match points to end-points of edges based on their geographical coordinates. I don't understand why edges are not simply specified by (u,v), where u and v are identifiers of the starting and ending nodes. Two edges (i,j) and (u,v) are then connected if j=u. At least this is how it's done in Openstreet maps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is metadata attached to the service that contains attribute information, the only way to get a description of the attributes is to contact whoever owns/maintains the service.

It doesn't appear to be an Esri/ArcGIS supplied service, rather it is hosted by a third-party (`sjrwmd.com`), so you may need to contact them directly for the information you require.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the underlying maps use Navteq's Navstreets Street Data (or the newer HERE map data). The definitions of these fields/attributes can be found in 
[NAVTEQ's Navstreets street data Reference Manual v4.4](http://mapworkspace.com/mw/showAttachment.do?workspaceKey=UTRfMjAxMl9OYXZzdHJlZXRz&documentID=368)

Each street segment indeed has a start node and an end node, modeled by resp. REF_IN_ID and NREF_IN_ID. How to get the coordinates corresponding with these points is still an open question for me.

Comment: If there is metadata for geospatial data, it is probably out there on someone's web page. Metadata is often standalone XML, which is very searchable. I have found metadata for files by searching for the attribute field names, sometimes with the word "metadata." If you can import any useful metadata to your file, other people may find it there. And they should thank you.